# How Unreal Engine 4 polls/handle input, in terms of input timing?

Tags: input, unreal-engine4

Precision more than 0.0166...second is required for certain genre of game, including rhythm action game. In this case, frame-based input handling might not be enough for players.

I'm a bit experienced in Unity, and I know that unity handled input per every frame(update call) until very recent version. This means that input from player is polled along with refresh rate of display, which is usually 60 frames per second.

Now I'm new to UE4, and want to know how it handles input from player. I see Tick, or Tickcomponent which seems to behave similar to Update in unity. (UE4 document says 'Function called every frame on this ActorComponent) Does UE4 also handle input per frame, or is timestamp available for input even though rendering frame would happen a bit later than actual input timing?

A scenario: input happened specifically at 4.052 second, and any frame-based call happened at 4.057 second.

In this case, does UE4 perceive input as happened at 4.052 or 4.057?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is frame based, not timestamped.
You can check it yourself.
Create a new C++ Class > Character.
In Visual Studio in that class find the Tick() and change it like that:

```
void NameOfClass::Tick(float DeltaTime)
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
    if (GetWorld() != nullptr)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("DeltaTime of Frame: %f"), GetWorld()->TimeSeconds)// Returns time in seconds since world was brought up for play, IS stopped when game pauses, IS dilated/clamped
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("DeltaTime of Frame FDateTime ms: %f"), FDateTime::Now().GetMillisecond())// Gets the local date and time on this computer.
    }
```

Then find one of the input functions e.g. Jump() and change it like that:

```
void NameOfClass::Jump()
{
    Super::Jump();
    if (GetWorld() != nullptr)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("DeltaTime of Jump: %f"), GetWorld()->TimeSeconds)// Returns time in seconds since world was brought up for play, IS stopped when game pauses, IS dilated/clamped
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("DeltaTime of Jump FDateTime ms: %f"), FDateTime::Now().GetMillisecond())// Gets the local date and time on this computer.
    }
}
```

Don't forget the #include for the UWorld at the top of the .cpp

```
#include "Runtime/Engine/Classes/Engine/World.h"
```

COMPILE.
In the UE4Editor Drag n Drop the class in your level, hit play, and you will see the DeltaTime of every frame is happening. If you press the space bar (calls by default the Jump()) and immediately ESC to stop the game, you can compare the 2 DeltaTimes. Identical!
I hope that answers your question.